# How to dock the panel

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I have install the script and i want to dock the panel in After effect.

[image]

I can just move the panel here and there is no option or snap so that i can dock it. The panel moving above the other panel and composition. Any suggestion how can i dock the panel.

Comment: To me.. that appears to be a **dialog window** and *not* a panel. Dialog windows don't "dock".

Comment: @Scott Its free plugin download from website.https://motionarray.com/tutorials/after-effects-tutorials/how-to/how-to-create-a-realistic-bouncing-effect-in-after-effects

Comment: It's a *script* not a "plug in". `:)` I know that may seem unimportant, but it's not. Scripts present dialog windows, they do not create panels. Plug ins can create panels.

Comment: @Scott I have install the motion Bro and flow also same way i cant dock it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it in the ScriptUI Panels folder, inside Scripts. This way it is stackable.